# Odd Behavior with Time Delta Series in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm running into an oddity where Pandas has a different mean for data in a timedelta format than it does for data converted to a float.

The screenshot below describes this more succinctly[image].

Does anyone know what the cause might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hit this just reported [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9442).

What happens is that `Timedelta` is represented in `nanoseconds`. When you sum these beyond the int64 max value they overflow (instead of throwing an error).

Will be address in the next release of pandas. For now you can use the work-around in the issues (which is similar to what you did).

Comment: Thanks! I spent a week tearing my hair out before deciding to post here. Didn't notice it was posted on the bugtracker after I checked